# Find HTML string and Remark

Tags: regex, batch-file, sed

I have an HTML creation script, and in it I am attempting to:

1.) Replace all instances of RelatedLinksBlock with a multi-line DOS variable using SED
2.) Find a string that matches a DOS variable and REM it out or delete it using SED

I cannot get either SED command to work after a couple of hours and need some help.

CODE:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set nl=^& echo.
set fullHTMLpath=http://this.com
set FileTitle=Computer TEST
set keyfile=test.html
set rempath=REMthisOUT
set "delpath=^<li^> - ^<a href="%fullHTMLpath%" title="%FileTitle%"^>%FileTitle%^</a^>^</li^>"
set "path1=^<li^> - ^<a href="http://that.com/computers-and-operating-systems/asus-computer-support.html" title="ASUS Computer Support"^>ASUS Computer Support^</a^>^</li^>"
set "path2=^<li^> - ^<a href="http://that.com/computers-and-operating-systems/asus-laptop-support.html" title="ASUS Laptop Support"^>ASUS Laptop Support^</a^>^</li^>"
set "path3=^<li^> - ^<a href="http://that.com/computers-and-operating-systems/asus-support.html" title="ASUS Support"^>ASUS Support^</a^>^</li^>"
set alllinks=%path1%%nl%%path2%%nl%%path3%

sed -i "s/RelatedLinksBlock/%alllinks%/g" "%keyfile%"
sed -i "s/%delpath%/%rempath%/g" "%keyfile%"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I know sed correctly, the newline should be \n for sed to process the newline character and not the batch file; and the forward slashes in the strings need to be escaped by a backslash.  Whenever characters \ / & are used literally, they need to be escaped.  Also there is nothing utilizing the Delayed Expansion in your snippet so I removed that.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set "fullHTMLpath=http:\/\/this.com"
set "FileTitle=Computer TEST"
set "keyfile=test.html"
set "rempath=REMthisOUT"
set "delpath=^<li^> - ^<a href="%fullHTMLpath%" title="%FileTitle%"^>%FileTitle%^<\/a^>^<\/li^>"
set "path1=^<li^> - ^<a href="http:\/\/that.com\/computers-and-operating-systems\/asus-computer-support.html" title="ASUS Computer Support"^>ASUS Computer Support^<\/a^>^<\/li^>"
set "path2=^<li^> - ^<a href="http:\/\/that.com\/computers-and-operating-systems\/asus-laptop-support.html" title="ASUS Laptop Support"^>ASUS Laptop Support^<\/a^>^<\/li^>"
set "path3=^<li^> - ^<a href="http:\/\/that.com\/computers-and-operating-systems\/asus-support.html" title="ASUS Support"^>ASUS Support^<\/a^>^<\/li^>"
set "alllinks=%path1%\n%path2%\n%path3%"

sed -i "s/RelatedLinksBlock/%alllinks%/g" "%keyfile%"
sed -i "s/%delpath%/%rempath%/g" "%keyfile%"
```

Other then those suggestions for now, are you getting any error messages you can show us?